# Как в apache отключить редирект https на localhost?

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, веб-сервер

Во время создания vhost на локалхосте возникает проблема с редиректом на https. Подскажите пожалуйста как отключить редирект https ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

или

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Так Вы включаете редирект с https на http

2. Зайти в папку где создаются vhost файлы там найти нужный файл где прописан домен с портом 443 и удалить этот файл.
3. Если пользуетесь веб интерфейсом (например: Wemin). Зайти в категорию  Веб-сервер apache, найти там домен с портом 443 и удалить его оттуда. Не забудьте перезапустить apache.

Comment: спасибо разобрался